# A group of 30 dice are thrown. What is the probability that 5 of each of the values 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 appear?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A group of 30 dice are thrown. What is the probability that 5 of each of the values 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 appear?

I solved the problem myself and got (30!)/(5!5!5!5!5!5!) as an answer, since you want 5 of 6 different values. However, when looking at the solutions provided by my professor, it says the answer is (30!)/(5!5!5!5!5!).

Comment: Both of those answers are well above 1 and a probability cannot be above 1. Are those just the number of combinations?

Comment: Remy is correct, but you are correct that the count should be $\cdot \frac{30!}{5!^6}.$ and then divide by $6^{30}$ to get the probability.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I forgot to include that part of the problem as it was the only part I was sure about. Thanks guys.

Comment: One way to think about it is that the count is the coefficient of $x_1^5x_2^5x_3^5x_4^5x_5^5x_6^5$ in $(x_1+\cdots+x_6)^{30}$, which is the multinomial $\binom{30}{5,5,5,5,5,5}$ which is your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an alternate approach to solving this and how I would think about it.

You first put down the $1$'s in $5$ positions. There are $30\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

You next put down the $2$'s in $5$ positions. There are $25\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

You next put down the $3$'s in $5$ positions. There are $20\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

You next put down the $4$'s in $5$ positions. There are $15\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

You next put down the $5$'s in $5$ positions. There are $10\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

Finally, you put down the $6$'s in $5$ positions. There are $5\choose{5}$ ways to do this.

Multiplying all these together, you get $\approx 8.88\cdot10^{19}$
 which is the same thing you'd get from doing $$\frac{30!}{(5!)^6}$$

Then multiply by $\frac{1}{6}^{30}$, since there is a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ that a given number gets put in a given slot, to get

$${\frac{30!}{(5!)^6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}}^{30}\approx 4.02\cdot10^{-4}$$

Comment: Interestingly enough, that was my first tactic at solving the problem, and the method I preferred. I was just so confused by the solution sheet I began to doubt myself. Probably just a typo.

Comment: why can't you use Bose-Einstein theorem  choose(10,5) to count the total ways of getting 5 particles in 6 distinct 'bins' ??

Comment: Because there is an equal probability of each result. In Bose-Einstein P(1,2,0) != P(3,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way of looking at this problem. There are $6^{30}$ possibilities. To count he favorable ones, treat the rolls as 30 characters that can be rearranged: 111112222233333...66666

There are $30!/(5!)^6$ arrangements which leads us to our answer $30!/(5!^6\times6^{30})$.